# How to use ngClass in Angular

Tags: angular

I have the below piece of code in angular to show icons with for `ngClass` and `class`:

```
<i
            class="icon warning status-indicator warning statusIcon "
            [ngClass]="{
              warning: alarmType === ('ucmgmt.onPremError.emergency' | translate),
              warning: alarmType === ('ucmgmt.onPremError.critical' | translate),
              warning: alarmType === ('common.alert' | translate),
              warning: alarmType === ('ucmgmt.onPremError.error' | translate),
              danger: alarmType === ('ucmgmt.onPremError.warning' | translate),
              info: alarmType === ('ucmgmt.onPremError.info' | translate)
            }"
          ></i
          >
```

What I have to show is if the icon has text `Emergency` or `Critical` or `Alert` or `Error`, it has to use the class warning. Currently my ngClass is not working as expected. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to put quotes around the class names, e.g. 'warning' and 'danger', but really I think your issue is that you need to combine the conditions for warning. What is the value of alarmType? Do you need the `| translate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the class name. It should be in single quotes.
I also changed the code a bit.

```html
<i class="icon warning status-indicator warning statusIcon "
  [ngClass]="{
    'warning': (alarmType === ('ucmgmt.onPremError.emergency' | translate) 
    || alarmType === ('ucmgmt.onPremError.critical' | translate) 
    || alarmType === ('common.alert' | translate)
    || alarmType === ('ucmgmt.onPremError.error' | translate)),
    'danger': alarmType === ('ucmgmt.onPremError.warning' | translate),
    'info': alarmType === ('ucmgmt.onPremError.info' | translate)
  }"></i>
```

Comment: Nice, there's just an extra comma at the end of the `common.alert` line